# Adapting Halo H71CT for 12" joist centers

Tags: recessed-lighting

I bought 24 6" recessed can lights for a new rec room. They're going between joists 12" on center.  I love the quick installation features of this assembly (got at Lowe's) but I snapped the guide arms according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZ0rUF8v7Yc).

Now I can't pull the guide arms apart. Anyone have experience with this before I ruin any more fixtures experimenting?

Comment: Please accept your answer to resolve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the video was wrong.  The pamphlet that comes with the light has instructions for breaking off these arms at the score points. You have to bend them in the right direction.  I tried another one and this worked fine.